# Flatten Folder Structure, Move Files from Sub-Folders to Main

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

In Windows command line, is there a way to bulk move all the contents of subfolders up some levels? In other words, a way to get rid of selected subfolders while keeping their contents? I would like to be able to drag the artist into the batch and have the structure flattened like that.

I'd like to go from:

```
e:\Artist
e:\Artist\Album
e:\Artist\Album\FLAC (24bit-44.1kHz)
e:\Artist\Album\FLAC (24bit-44.1kHz)\01 - Track#1.flac
e:\Artist\Album\FLAC (24bit-44.1kHz)\02 - Track#2.flac
e:\Artist\Album\FLAC (24bit-44.1kHz)\03 - Track#3.flac
```

to:

```
e:\Artist - Album - FLAC [24-44]\01 - Track#1.flac
e:\Artist - Album - FLAC [24-44]\02 - Track#2.flac
e:\Artist - Album - FLAC [24-44]\03 - Track#1.flac
```

Thanks!!!